# iOS 13.4 Crashes app with vague message: precondition failure: type check failed: 101, expected Text, got _HiddenModifier

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, ios13.4

Sorry to be vague in the description here, but this has caused my app to be completely DOA when a user attempts to use my search feature. This did not happen before iOS 13.4 and the error message is not helpful at all. Cant find any info. Has anyone run into this? where could it be?

The app crashes at the point where in my SwiftUI file, I populate the view using a ForEach from an array, which is an observable object:

`ForEach(self.listArray.searchDataArray, id: \.self) { fetchedData in`

Ill update if I figure it out, wanted to see who else has experienced this and what possible causes could be.

Thank you!

Comment: That's why it'd be much better to use UIKitPlus instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue:

This line of code, which i added to avoid screen glitches in swiftUI caused it:

Text("").hidden()

commented it out and it all works fine..

weird!

Comment: its just scary that when an update comes out, it can simply break random things.. Got nervous looking for the solution, luckily I found it quickly.. But so random.